# Как правильнее реализовать такую связь?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

как лучше реализовать данную связь. Есть model Product и Category
Для Category я задал и поля Products ( массив) , (Types.ObjectId, rel="Category').
Для Product я задал поля Category ( не массив , ибо выбор одной категории) . (Types.objectId, rel='Product')

По логике при добавления товара мы выбираем нужную категорию из выбора( select) в котором перечисляются все категории. И тогда у каждого продукта будет поля category в котором находятся ID нужной категории. Но каким образом сделать что бы при добавлении ID данного продукта попадал в массив нужной категории.

Comment: не нужно никак. в категории не нужно хранимое поле ссылающееся на продукт.

Comment: @nörbörnën , Я сделал след образом. Продукт хранит информацию ИД категории. При выводе в категорию, идет обращения к всем продуктам и на стороне клиента через простую проверку рендеряться нужные продукты. Но обращения к серверу идет на все продукты и мне кажется это не совсем корректно

Comment: и так тоже не надо! ну что тебе стоит на бэке в выборке продуктов сделать фильтр по категории? указана категория - фильтруешь, не указана - не фильтруешь